# Xcode 7.0 XCTest dyld: could not load inserted library IDEBundleInjection

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode7, dyld

I'm running unit tests on my iOS project and when it's running, it crashes and spits this out:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1CAB64C8-D730-427B-8E9E-BD5E152ACFD6/tmp/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1CAB64C8-D730-427B-8E9E-BD5E152ACFD6/tmp/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection: mmap() error 1 at address=0x00436000, size=0x00004000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1CAB64C8-D730-427B-8E9E-BD5E152ACFD6/tmp/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection
```

I'm using XCode 7.0 and testing on an iPod running iOS 8.3. I have deleted the derived data and I've restarted XCode and it still hasn't worked.

Comment: Does this happen on an iOS 9.0 device/simulator? It might be caused by using the Xcode 7 beta on an incompatible iOS version.

Comment: I run my unit tests on the device itself because some of my frameworks are arm7-only. The device I'm using is an iPod running 8.3.

Comment: I had the same problem with an iPhone 5 (iOS 9.1) but if I use simulator it works correctly

Comment: I have the same issue... It runs well on simulator but not on device, do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this by just creating a new UnitTest target, copying everything over, and removing the old one.

Comment: If you got a better answer, feel free to post and I'll select yours. This post has been voted up several times so people want an answer even if it's not the best one.

Comment: Oh sorry that wasn't a criticism. I upvoted it myself. It was just a sarcastic statement of the truth.

Comment: this only worked for me after rebooting the device(iOS10 device in Xcode8)

Answer (score 5):

In General Panel , not leave the Team to "None"

[image]

At Same time : select the code sign in Build Setting->Code Signing-> Code Signing Identity

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix this by specifying my developer certificate in `build settings->code signing identity`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by selecting the correct target and then selecting the correct Code Signing Identity from Settings. It was set to a non default - changed to 'IOS Developer' for the Debug setting entry.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was nothing wrong with the provisioning profiles, it was down to the Architectures in the project excluding arm64. Once arm64 was added to both the test target and the host app target the tests ran fine (On Xcode 7.2). The error was:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A94F5AD3-2A5F-415D-B127-0F45DEC7A659/tmp/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A94F5AD3-2A5F-415D-B127-0F45DEC7A659/tmp/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection: mmap() error 22 at address=0x00501000, size=0x00005960 segment=__LINKEDIT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A94F5AD3-2A5F-415D-B127-0F45DEC7A659/tmp/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection
```

Comment: and how did you add arm64?

Comment: Just in 'Build Settings' for both the app target and the test target, add `arm64` to the 'Architectures' and to the 'Valid Architectures'.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and had to reboot my device.  I was using iOS 10 with Xcode 8.0 (developing in swift 3.0)

Comment: Same here; a device reboot worked fine. Restarted Xcode as well for good measure. iOS 10.2.1, Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3.0 project.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the team under Project->App Target->General.  It was set to "None", instead of a valid team.

Answer (score 0):

I had my base SDK in XCode Build Settings set to a more recent version of iOS than the phone had, so I had to upgrade the OS on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by rebooting my iOS Device.