# dyld: could not load inserted library

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ui-automation, dyld

When I try to run an UI and Unit tests, I get an exception:

> dyld: could not load inserted library
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application//AutoTestingApp.app/Frameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection'
>   because no suitable image found.  Did find:
>
> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest

App builds with success but fails when running a test.

I already tried:

- reinstalling Xcode
- checking a provisioning profiles and a certificates

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you might be able to avoid this issue by running your test on a simulator instead of the device.  Also make sure you've set your profiles correctly: i.e. [Xcode 7.0 XCTest dyld: could not load inserted library IDEBundleInjection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405833/xcode-7-0-xctest-dyld-could-not-load-inserted-library-idebundleinjection)