# DTDeviceKit: Could not start house arrest service for app identifier XXX

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, dyld

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and executing XCTest via the command-line on my device, "iPhone 1", which is an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.3.5:

```
xcodebuild \
  -scheme Todo \
  -project Todo.xcodeproj \
  -destination "platform=iOS,name=iPhone 1"\
clean build test
```

The build succeeded, however it failed after compiling the test files:

```
2016-09-13 14:51:32.604 xcodebuild[79689:2064116]  DTDeviceKit: Could not start house arrest service for app identifier com.example.Todo [Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402653093 "Too many instances of this service are already running." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Too many instances of this service are already running., com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010fead3cb DTDKCreateNSError + 113
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010feadb09 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 791
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010febf2f5 __70-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startHouseArrestServiceForAppIdentifier:]_block_invoke + 100
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010febe1d1 __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_4 + 22
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010feb0317 __DTDKExecuteInSession_block_invoke + 38
    5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010feaf940 __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke_2 + 477
    6   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010feaf73c __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke + 107
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff99bda40b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff99bdb9f2 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 74
    9   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106400bef DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 206
    10  DVTFoundation                       0x00000001063dd59b -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 116
    11  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010feaf646 DTDKExecuteWithConnection + 223
    12  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010feb02a1 DTDKExecuteInSession + 121
    13  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010febe108 __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_3 + 117
    14  DVTFoundation                       0x00000001063fff4b __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 827
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff99be593d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff99bda40b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff99becbd7 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 1733
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff99bda40b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff99bde29b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff99bddb00 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9b5d94de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9b5d7341 start_wqthread + 13
), NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Too many instances of this service are already running., NSLocalizedDescription=Too many instances of this service are already running.}]
2016-09-13 14:51:32.918 xcodebuild[79689:2063388] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}
```

Running the tests in Xcode did not succeed either. And it always fails with the errors described in these posts:

- [dyld: could not load inserted library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072873/dyld-could-not-load-inserted-library)
- [Xcode 7.0 XCTest dyld: could not load inserted library IDEBundleInjection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405833/xcode-7-0-xctest-dyld-could-not-load-inserted-library-idebundleinjection)

I've tried the solutions suggested in the posts (i.e. fix provisioning profile and code signing), but it did not help. Has anyone faced similar problems?

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7192

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was trying to find out if `DTDeviceKit` was running on my machine, but it did not. My next suspicion was that it could be running on the phone.

After rebooting my phone, it works.

Comment: too bad there isn't a way to fix this without needing to reboot the phone everytime... I hope apple is aware of the bug and is going to fix it...

Comment: Restarting the phone works for me too. Sucks that theres not a better understanding of why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I filed a technical support ticket with apple.  Turns out it's a bug which affects 32 bit devices.  So if you test on a 64 bit device you won't have this issue.

Comment: I just saw it in a 64-bit device. I think it just takes much longer to manifest in such devices.

Comment: ok, best let apple know, they might try harder to fix it if that's the case :)

Comment: Maybe you can tell that to the support engineer you worked with?

Comment: Unfortunately it was a company account so don't have access anymore

Comment: Happens to me on iPhone 4S and iPhone 6S that are connected to Mac Jenkins slave. It is annoying to reboot device every time this happens.